# Is it possible to convert an event log provider name to the event log source shown in eventvwr?

Tags: powershell, event-viewer

I'm writing a script which is essentially a simple frontend to the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet--the one issue I'm seeing arise is that when specifying a filter to the `-FilterHashTable` parameter, then `ProviderName` property does not match what is actually shown in the eventvwr console.

Does anyone know of a way to convert from ProviderName to the Source property shown in the console?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a sample and picture of the eventlog to show the mismatch? Because Hey Scripting Guy says "The ProviderName is the name that appears in the Source field in the Event Viewer.", and that has been true the times I've used it.

Comment: Yep I read that as well, but for instance if you look at "DistributedCOM" errors in the event log the actual provider is "Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" -- same with "HttpEvent" source being "Microsoft-Windows-HttpEvent."